# Macro not working: 'Compile error: Object library feature not supported'

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I run this macro I get:

> Compile error: Object library feature not supported' with the 'Set ws1 =' highlighted.

What's happening? Is something wrong?

Thanks

```
Sub Airpush()
'Define your variables.
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, cel As Range, i As Long

'Assign your worksheet variables.
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CAMPAIGN_PLANNER")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT_DOWNLOAD")

    'First loop through each cell in Sheet2, Column E, (start at row 2 to account
    'for header row) to get the value to find in Sheet1, Column C.
    For Each cel In ws2.Range("A2:A" & ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        'Then loop through each cell in Sheet1, column C. If you get a match, then
        'copy the value from Sheet2, column B, cel.row to Sheet1, Column S, i row.
        For i = 2 To ws1.Range("L" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            If cel.Value = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value Then
                ws1.Cells(i, 3).Offset(, 16).Value = cel.Offset(, 3).Value
                ws1.Cells(i, 3).Offset(, 15).Value = cel.Offset(, 4).Value
                ws1.Cells(i, 3).Offset(, 17).Value = cel.Offset(, 2).Value
            End If

        Next i 'loops through every used cell in Column C for all matches
    Next cel 'loop to the next cell in Sheets2, Columns E

End Sub
```

Comment: You 100% sure that sheet names are correct?

Comment: @Teamothy yes 100%, I'm using an excel that isn't activated yet, but this macro has worked on this PC in the past? Very confused.

Comment: Do you have some referenced libraries being used, that perhaps have been updated?

Comment: in VBE, Click on `Tools|References`. Uncheck any missing libraries. It will start with the word `MISSING: ...`

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` says that both the *macro code* and the worksheet(s) are in the *same* workbook? Is that the case, or is the macro code in another workbook? I ask because you say " I'm using an excel that isn't activated yet" which indicates it *might* be in a different workbook?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-object-library-feature-not-supported/4896e73f-2934-4fa6-bd04-28c713d6ff9d

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was, however when I re-opened the excel on an activated version the macro worked fine, suggesting the issue is something to do with the read-only version.

Thanks to everyone who commented!